# Get login form to open on pageload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I have a login page, it's not opening the login form when it loads to the login page. Not really sure what I'm missing as I don't really know JavaScript that well. Here is what I have so far.

```
<body>

    <h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
    {@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
        <form>

            <p style="text-align:center">Please login using your <strong><em>Username and Password</em></strong></p>

            <table class="center">

                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:17px">
                        Username
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginUserName)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoginUserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:17px">
                        Password
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right:30px">
                        Remember Me
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]" /></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

}
</body>


</html>

@if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                alert("@ViewBag.Message")
            });
    </script>

}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () { myForm(); }, 30000);
</script>
```

**Result**
I just need the login form to pop up after someone clicks on the login link. After successful login, it will reroute to the home page.

Comment: `myForm` is not defined in the code example.

Comment: @evolutionxbox that would be ```var myForm = ``` correct?

Comment: Yes, that would define what `myForm` is. `form-popup` means nothing to us without the accompanying CSS/JS. The @ syntax code may not be useful either (razor?) as it doesn't seem to help diagnose the issue. Make sure the example in the question is a [mcve].

Comment: @evolutionxbox if you want to answer the question, I'll mark it so. I did have the login form as hidden in my CSS because I had it showing as a button that needed to be clicked. Thank you. That was my problem.

Comment: What was the solution?!

Comment: I had the css class ```form-popup```  with the parameter ```display: none;```. I took that away, and it now shows up. Don't even need javascript.

Comment: Ok. Good. I couldn't have written an answer as I didn't know the solution.